# R Plotting two datasets with smoothScatter() with the same color scheme

Tags: r, plot, colors, density-plot

I would like to plot the two dimensional densities of two different datasets using the `smoothScatter()` function:

```
smoothScatter(confdiffCovCorrect$meth.diff, confdiffCovCorrect$qvalue)
smoothScatter(logdiffCovCorrect$meth.diff, logdiffCovCorrect$qvalue)`
```

But, in order to compare the two datasets using the plots, I want the color code to be identical. That is, I want a given value Xi of the density function to correspond to the same color in both plots.

Is this possible?