# Comparing smoothScatter plots R

Tags: r, transformation, scaling

I'm generating many density plots in R using smoothScatter.
I was wondering if it is possible to set the maximum in the colramp so I compare density plots between datasets.
smoothScatter automatically normalises the colramp, so I can't compare density plots visually.
I'd like to get density plots where the maximum is set in the colramp.

This questions was asked before, but nobody answered:
[R Plotting two datasets with smoothScatter() with the same color scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29891478/7258016)

Code:

```
fudgeit <- function(){
  xm <- get('xm', envir = parent.frame(1))
  ym <- get('ym', envir = parent.frame(1))
  z  <- get('dens', envir = parent.frame(1))
  colramp <- get('colramp', parent.frame(1))
  image.plot(xm,ym,z, col = colramp(256), legend.only = T, add =T)
}

Lab.palette <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "orange", "red"), space = "Lab")
smoothScatter(sub3, colramp = Lab.palette, postPlotHook = fudgeit)
```

[Density scaling issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dRW0.png)